# I'm trying to change font color in One Note trough an autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey, onenote

Im using this code in the autohotkey converter because I would like to press for example: 
'ctrl + alt + r' to change the font color

```
SetTitleMatchMode, RegEx ; match window titles by regular expressions

#IfWinActive - OneNote$ ; ------ only in windows with title ending with "- OneNote"

^!p::Send, !hfca!hfc{Down 7}{Right 4}{Enter}
^!r::Send, !hfcm^{PgDn}!r255{Tab}5{Tab}0{Enter} ; red (255, 0, 0)
^!b::Send, !hfcm^{PgDn}!r0{Tab}5{Tab}255{Enter} ; blue (0, 0, 255)
^!a::Send, !hfca ; automatic color (i.e. reset font color to "none")

#IfWinActive ; ------ end of section restricted to specific windows
```

I executed this code trough the .exe file but nothing happened

Comment: This worked for me. I opened OneNote.exe (not UWP) and tried each of your hotkeys; each worked. A couple things to (one)note: the `^{PgDn}` will go back to the first tab if the `^!r` or `^!b` hotkeys are used an even number of times; the "red" hotkey actually sets the color to 255, 5, 0 and "blue" to 0, 5, 255. Additionally, it may be much more reliable to control OneNote using `ControlSend` or COM.

Comment: What does "*I executed this code trough the .exe file but nothing happened*" mean? Is your script compiled?